# AutoHotKey Script for date time function, what code for "MM" may be substituted to provide the month as text "i.e. NOV, DEC, etc." my script follows

Tags: windows, datetime, replace, integer, autohotkey

My current script is:

#z::
FormatTime, CurrentpateTime„ MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss -{SPACE}
sendInput %CurrentDateTlme%
return

I wish to have the month display as text In the resultant output [JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, etc.]

I wish to be able to enter date time sequences with a keysstroke anywhere I am working on my PC. I simply do not know the code for 01, 02,

I googled "what is the text code for the Integer month dates" However, the returns are specific to Excel rather than general docs such as Google docs

Answer (score 1):

If you are after month format as JAN, FEB..., you can use `MMM` date format.
From documentation:

```
MMM     Abbreviated month name (e.g. Jan) in the current user's language
```

For example:

```
FormatTime, CurrentpateTime,, MMM
StringUpper, result, CurrentpateTime
MsgBox %result%
```

will display : `DEC`